# calling javascript from rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have started working on rails, i m trying to call a javascript from rails controller
    The structure is as follows

`app/controllers/
    hello_controller.rb

  def search

      //calling show.js.erb

  end
   app/views/hello/show.js.erb`

**Basically i want to call a html file(div tag) from a javascript**

`The point is i want to do nothing when the page is opened , but to run the javascript when show button is hit`
**same point - write in controller**

`respond_to do |format|
   format.html{
         }
         format.js{ render template: 'show', layout: false }
      end`

and in show.js.erb i wrote
alert("Hello");

**NOT WORKING !**

Comment: Would you like to show this for HTML requests, or just AJAX requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way is following:

```
def search
  @var = Model.where(name: params[:search]) # will be available in search.js.erb
  respond_to :js # will try to render search.js.erb in views/hello/
end
```

You can render custom js file:

```
def search
  # some code..
  respond_to :js { render 'show' }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def search
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js{ render template: 'show', layout: false }
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: do i need to mention some path anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller put the code some thing like this to suite with your application

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js # actually means: if the client ask for js -> return file.js
end
```